# Impinge: transitive or intransitive?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitivity

The OED states that the verb "impinge" is intransitive. However, example sentences such as the following have (as I see it) the verb taking a direct object (highlighted in bold):

> Several factors impinge on **market efficiency**.
>
> The proposed fencing would impinge on **a public bridleway**.

In the above sentences, is the verb not transitive?

Comment: To 'impinge on' something is an indirect object. You are looking for something or someone to 'impinge' something for it to be a direct object.Your examples are both intransitive as there is no direct object there in either case.

Comment: @Nigel J "To 'impinge on' something is an indirect object." makes no sense. And no analysis would consider there to be an indirect object involved here.

Comment: @Nigel J If a prepositional phrase is involved here, which I don't believe is the case, an indirect object is not involved. If a multi-word verb is involved, it takes a direct object.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I look forward to up-voting your answer once you submit it.

Comment: I can't; I've posted my views in a 'comment' below, but don't consider dictionary POS-tagging sufficient endorsement here. I've not found a grammar voting on whether 'impinge on our rights' should be analysed as V + PP or MWV + DO.

Answer (score 4):

No, it would not be classified as transitive—at least, not according to the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*'s definition of transitivity.

A transitive verb, such as *crush*, takes a noun phrase called the "direct object" as a complement. (E.g. noun phrase "the lemon" in "I crushed the lemon" is the direct object of the verb *crush*.)

In the sentences you give, *impinge* takes a prepositional phrase headed by the preposition *on* as its complement. That prepositional phrase contains a noun phrase (sometimes called the "object of the preposition"), but the fact that this noun phrase is embedded in a prepositional phrase makes it not count as a direct object of the verb.

Both transitive and intransitive verbs can take complements, but of different types. Only verbs like *crush* that take noun phrases as complements are categorized as transitive verbs. *Impinge* would be transitive if you could say things like "Several factors impinge market efficiency." (The comments indicate that the OED records transitive uses of *impinge.*)

Related previous posts:

- [How is transitivity defined in CGEL?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481884/how-tran-si-tiv-ity-is-de-%ef%ac%81ned-in-cgel)

  Brett Reynolds' answer says:

  > For CGEL, transitive means specifically 'taking a object as complement'. Moreover, I recall personal discussions with Pullum and Huddleston in which they confirm that **only NPs function as objects**. **Verbs** or prepositions **which take other types of complements**, such as clausal complements, predicative complements, etc, **are not transitive.**
- [Intransitive or transitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235724/77227)

  Araucaria's answer says

  > An object is a special type of complement of a verb. [...] It is the preposition heading the preposition phrase which has a special relationship with the verb *apologise*. So because *someone* isn't a complement of the verb here, it cannot be considered a direct object.
- [call on - trans or intransitive verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/517137/77227)

  BillJ's answer says

  > **A verb is only transitive if it has a direct object** in the clause that contains it. [...] Note that **complements of prepositions are not direct** or indirect **objects**.

Therefore, the only way "impinge on something" could be transitive according to the CGEL definition of transitivity would be if "on something" did not constitute a prepositional phrase. I'm pretty inclined to say that "on market efficiency" and "on a public bridleway" are prepositional phrases, but some of the comments have suggested that the structure of your examples is "[impinge on] [noun phrase]" instead of "[impinge] [on noun phrase]". This issue is discussed in the following places:

- Greg Lee's answer to ["Transitive / intransitive verbs"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300971/77227) discusses that topic.
- This handout from a course taught by Bert Vaux and David Willis, professors at the University of Cambridge: "[Li8 Structure of English: Verbal syntax and complementation](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/li8/verbs.pdf)"

Another related post:

- [What is the real difference between direct objects and prepositional phrases?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274337/what-is-the-real-difference-between-direct-objects-and-prepositional-phrases)

Comment: All the dictionaries I've **checked** in consider 'impinge on/upon' to be a transitive 'phrasal verb' (in the terminology I prefer, a transitive multi-word verb). This is at odds with the simplex verb + prepositional phrase analysis you state (without supporting references). [These rules] [impinge on/upon] [our civil rights], not [These rules] [impinge] [on/upon our civil rights].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/92408), where all senses constructed with prepositions are deemed intransitive. In contrast, transitive citations from senses 1, 2, and 3: *If this method of appealing to the absurdities of a past age, and **impinging them** upon the present age is fair and just. // He **impinged his foot** with a force that overbalanced himself. // The striker's thumb .. **impinges the skull** of his opponent.* Adding *on* or *upon* makes it intransitive; from sense 6: *In doing so, I should be **impinging on** the province of the reviewers.*

Comment: @tchrist Yes; Lexico has 'no object' rather than 'intranisitive' for the usual  'impinge on/upon X' examples. Do you remember a question here addressing the different approaches?

Comment: I know of no grammatical system in which a verb which takes a non-nominal argument would be considered intransitive, and I can't really believe the CGEL would define it as such. Do you have direct quotes that they do? That linked question is talking about intransitive *prepositions*, not verbs.

Comment: @herisson That CGEL quote is truly astounding. I'll have to ask on [linguistics.se]. Maybe it's an idiosyncratic redefinition of Pullum and Huddleston.

Comment: Related Ling SE post: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-intransitive-verbs-with-dative-complement-called

Comment: +1, I agree with the analysis of CaGEL that verbs which take PPs as complements to be intransitive.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, those examples clearly show transitive uses of the verb *impinge*. The verb takes two arguments, a subject and a prepositional phrase. If a verb takes two arguments then it's transitive. In fact I can't think of any intransitive examples, unless you would count a clause with an elided argument (and I wouldn't, elision is a process that changes the final output, but doesn't change the natural valency of a verb IMO.):

> John: One factor impinges on market efficiency.
>
> Mark: No, many factors impinge.

Comment: Is "green" an argument of the verb *be* in the sentence "Grass is green"? If so, "is" has two arguments, "Grass" and "green," and so the verb *be* is transitive according to the definition given here.

Comment: @herisson Yes, in that example *is* is transitive.